# Retrieving data from sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to **return** all rows into an array using **cursor** without **specifying** any **column name** or **number**

Comment: Do you consider a `*` as a column name? As in `select * from table`?

Comment: Yes SELECT * FROM table_name ; and return all rows and columns using the cursor without specifying a column name or number in the cursor

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you will need the column indicies/names to extract the data out of the cursor. If you are trying to built a Listview, you should checkout the CursorAdapter classes

Comment: Yeah, custom list view, thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now its not possible using Android cursor api, however if you require repeatedly for your app, a customized utility method can be developed with just few lines of code, which will  take the table name as a parameters and return rows in  Array List or HashTable.